# 既に起動している Microsoft Edge のウィンドウをチェックする方法

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge

やりたいことは以下の2点です。

1. Micrsoft Edgeを `--app` オプションで起動する
2. `--app` で起動しているEdgeと同一のサイトへは同時に1画面しかアクセスさせない
   （すでに起動している状態で、同一サイトへアクセスしようとした場合にはポップアップでエラーを表示し、すでに起動している画面を最前面に表示するよう制御する）

- Edgeの起動はC#のアプリケーションから実行
- `--app` で起動するサイトは１つのみ許容する
- 他のサイトへのアクセスは並行稼働することを許容する

上記の想定で、すでに起動しているedgeプロセスがある場合に、同一サイト（アプリ）へのアクセスかを判定する方法をご教示いただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

なんだか[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)の感じがします。本当にやりたい事あるいは制限しなければならない条件などがあって、それを実現するために考え付いた手段が質問内容になっているのでは？

---

例えば単純に考えるとそれは`Micrsoft Edge`から何か情報を取得したり動作を依頼したりするのではなく、`C#で作るEdgeランチャープログラム`が自分の責任範囲内で処理を行えば良いのでは？

- 名前付きMutexを使ったプログラムの多重起動を禁止する記事は色々な所に見受けられるので、それらを参考に`C#で作るEdgeランチャープログラム`が多重に起動しないように出来るでしょう。
- `C#で作るEdgeランチャープログラム`は、そのメイン処理の中で`Micrsoft Edgeを --app オプションで起動`し、起動したEdgeが終了するまで常駐して監視すれば良いのでは？
  自分自身で起動したプログラムなので、PID等のプロセス情報は分かっているだろうし、そのプロセスが終了(強制中断などでも)するのを待って`C#で作るEdgeランチャープログラム`が終了するようにすれば良いでしょう。

---

ただし、`C#で作るEdgeランチャープログラム`を使わず手作業で同等の`Micrsoft Edgeを --app オプションで起動`することは止められませんし、ChromeやFirefoxを使う形でアクセスすることも止められないでしょう。

本当に強固な制限を課したいのならば、個々のPCやネットワークでファイヤーウォール/ウィルスチェッカー/Proxyサーバー/Gatewayサーバー等の全てで汎用のブラウザ等によるそのサイトへのアクセスを禁止しておき、[Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/)などのコントロールを使った専用のプログラムだけがアクセス出来るようにするとかが考えられます。

そうした専用のプログラムならば、1つしか起動/アクセスができないとかの制限や何か独特の振る舞いを実装するのも自分で変更することのできない汎用プログラムよりは容易に出来るでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。たしかにご指摘のとおり質問のしかたがまずかったです。

Comment: まず、前提として画面要件を実現するため--appでedgeを起動することが決まっており、その状態で、特定のサイトにアクセスする-appで起動したedgeのみ多重起動を抑止し他のサイトへのedgeでのアクセスは可能とするよう制御したいという要件になります。

MUTEXでの複数起動制御も検討しましたが、「ただし、C#で作るEdgeランチャープログラムを使わず手作業で同等のMicrsoft Edgeを --app オプションで起動することは止められません」の記載のとおりでした。

Comment: 追加の説明はコメントで行うのではなく、質問記事を編集して追記してください。また公開できない情報もあるでしょうから、そこは書かないとかボカすとかで良いですが、`--app`オプションに決めたという画面要件の理由まで立ち返って代替手段が無いか検討し直した方が良いのでは？ というか一番重要な要件は画面では無く他にあるから、質問のようなプラスアルファの項目が付いてきているのでは？と言う風にも見えます。